# Chrome navigation list positioning bug with media queries in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

This might be a Chrome/webkit rendering bug, but I want to check if I'm doing something wrong first.

I have a simple UL/LI navigation, each LI is inline-block to appear horizontally. The UL is text-align: right. 
The 2nd to last element is positioned absolute to the top right corner of the page. The last element is positioned relative to push it down a little bit.

For mobile devices (max-width 400px) there is a media query to reset elements into a standard top-down stacked list, 100px wide.

If you load the page in the wide screen width, everything is fine. If you load the page in the mobile screen width, everything is fine. But if you start in the mobile screen width, and extend your width, Chrome will render the list elements **in a broken way**: element Five will **appear on the next line**, even though there is plenty of room to fit next to the other elements.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>li One</li>
    <li>li Two</li>
    <li>li Three</li>
    <li class="abs">li Four</li>
    <li class="last">li Five</li><!-- This element should always appear to the right of "Three" in the wide screen width -->
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    background: lightblue;
    padding: 20px 0;
    text-align: right;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    min-width: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

li.abs {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;    
    z-index: 9;
}

.last {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 8px;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100px;
    }

    li.abs {
        position: static;   
    }

    .last {
        position: static;
        margin: 0;
    }
}
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Actual Output (after resizing window):

[image]

Firefox has no problems at all. This is Chrome 31.
Simplified JSFiddle Test Case: http://jsfiddle.net/ZE3Kk/4/

Comment: Works for me, Chrome 32. That would mean it's a recently patched bug then.

Comment: @Joeytje50 Did you resize the window? I'm running Chrome32 and im seeing everything described.

Comment: Did you try dragging the slider to small and big again to confirm the expected output is always shown?

Comment: In both Firefox and Chrome 32 it does the same for me: it switches between http://i.imgur.com/ZbLeUjZ.png (top is wide, bottom is resized). Ohhhhhhh wait, I see it now, never mind about it working :x

Comment: The problem is that something is causing Chrome (also v.32) to not "reflow" the elements properly after a media query change. Sure, it works fine on initial page load. But *after the media query change* it breaks. I'll file this as a bug in Chrome but I'm willing to accept a work-around for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZE3Kk/8/

```
li.abs div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;    
    width: 60px;
    height: 25px;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9;
}
```

Solution was to insert a DIV inside the LI, keep the LI position standard, but absolutely position the DIV. By doing this, Chrome does not break the elements when changing media queries.

**Update**: Found a related Chromium bug that demonstrates this problem in a different way -> https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=147449

Answer (score 0):

try to use float: right for your li's:

```
li {
display: block;
padding: 5px;
background: blue;
float: right;
color: white;
min-width: 50px;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

and just switch all the elements so they will have the order that you need, and it will work after resizing

here is the example with float, now just re-arrange the menu items http://jsfiddle.net/ZE3Kk/6/

Comment: sorry, I was tweaking the same JSFiddle and I'm up to version 8 now. I think your version 6 was overwritten by me. Anyway, I found a solution to prevent this "Chrome reflow" issue. Posting as answer